# Looking for a gallery on drupal 7

Tags: views, media

this is my site on blogger [mysite](http://www.luckyone.eu/)

I decide to do it again on drupal as my first website. I cannot find any way (module or view) to make the content look like my site. I don't want exactly the same. I want only the image and if I hover the mouse, then with effect I can see the title or other fields.

Do you know anything like this?

Update. Describe the gallery:

The gallery in my previous site was a grid like that one on views, but when you hover the image on the grid, the image sliding down and title and description show. I have try to do it with views's grid, but I cannot find a way to add an effect.

The last option for me is to take the css from my previous site and modifying in for the new one, but I prefer a easier way like a module.

Comment: Hello. See [this help page](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), especially "and it is not about" part, point "Implementing a functionality, or a layout seen in a site, for which only a screenshot or a site URL is provided". Could you describe your desired functionality without a need for a link? And tell us what you tried or what was your idea to approach this, and how did it failed you? Note that providing a whole theming guide would be way too broad for Q&A format.

Comment: @Mołot I add more details, so you can understand what I want without visiting the link. Just to make it clear. This is not "a site", but my site. I want to redesign it with drupal

Comment: That rule is there to make sure question makes sense even if the linked server is no longer available, so it hardly matters if it's your site or not :)

Comment: I didn't know that. I thought that it was for "stealing" sites. Now, my question is better?

Comment: Seems so. I'll check in one of my old projects, if it wasn't custom code, I'll share. If it was, sorry, it's sold and I no longer have rights for it. For stealing sites - this rule would not prevent it anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently did a similar site to that css effect, http://www.chinafile.com

This was my process, but this is just a general idea of how i did it:

1. create new View and display in the following order in the format of a Grid: image, title, body (truncated). now all your fields will be stacked on top of another.
2. CSS absolute position the image so everything below it will float up into the image.
3. set the title and body to display:none
4. create a css :hover event to change the title and body to display:block once you hover.

Thats the general idea behind how to do that type of effect. Now if you wanted it to animate you will need to use the CSS property transition:

Its mainly going to be CSS and creating a View. No need to modify any HTML or any extra coding.

Comment: Thank you @duckx. I will wait the answer of Molot, since he said that he will search for it and I will check "best answer" after that

Comment: if your not that familiar with css, i suggest you create a blank.html document on your computer and test it out first so you can get an idea of how to make it work locally.

Comment: I know all those you said except transition. I will give it a try to see how it looks

Answer (score 0):

If the main purpose of this gallery is displaying the products, I think first you need to do is to create a content type "**Product**" and add fields like: **image, link, category** (term reference).

Then you can create a view page showing fields in grid format.

The most important settings:

**Fields** (title, body, image)

**Filter** (Content type: Product)

**Path** (e.g: /product/category/%)

**Contextual filter** ( Content: Has taxonomy term ID )  - in order to filter the results according to the category you need to provide raw value from URL and validate as a taxonomy term converted to term ID (I can clarify this step if you'll need to)

Rest of work is based on CSS

I think it should be the base of your gallery, just add some work and you'll get the same result as this one on your site.